# Google Maps API V3 Store Locator

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a store locator for my work. I've seen this done before using Google Maps API V2, but have not seen a good example using V3.

Here's a mockup of what I'm aiming to get working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIRqv.jpg

I think it's a pretty simple concept, but what I'm having trouble getting to work is the parts pertaining to the stores themselves.

Does anyone know of any examples, tutorials or demos of something similar to the image linked above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: This related question may help you debug when making a store locator: [Google Maps API - geocode() doesn't return lat and long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481848/google-maps-api-geocode-doesnt-return-lat-and-long)

The V3 API for a store locator is horrible!

I used [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html) and many functions weren't defined.

Everything was going fine for me until I got to the XML parsing, then Google's API started breaking on me.  Absolutely deplorable, IMHO.

Comment: Ya, I ended up sort of having to jerry-rig it together myself. On the plus, I got what I needed in the end.

Comment: I ended up making a store locator by using javascript and JSON from the V3 API.

FYI, the JSON object that you get from Google isn't formatted correctly (the names are off).  Debug with your browser or message me for help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there **is** a V3 version of this article.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html

Answer (score 0):

I followed this documentation for creating a store locator: http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I used the Google Code one (maybe that's the one you already saw)..

http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

Granted it's for API V2 but its actually very easy updating it to  API V3.. Just have look at he API V3 reference when in doubt..

http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

Answer (score -1):

I use this this API as it makes it real simple, can do a store locator in couple of hours
http://www.ehoundplatform.com/developers/documentation-developers/store-locator-using-freehound-and-google-maps-v-3

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.