# Google Maps API - geocode() doesn't return lat and long

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to get a latitude and longitude by address with the following code:

```
 function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = "HaYarkon 100 TelAviv Israel";
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
       {
            TelAviv = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.latitude,results[0].geometry.location.longitude);             
       }
    });

    var myOptions = {
        zoom:7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: TelAviv
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
```

The problem is that results[0].geomety.location.latitude and longitude are undefinde.

What I see in the results in the console are the next:

```
 location: O

   $a: 51.5414691

   ab: -0.11492010000006303
```

Why does it show $a and ab instead of latitude and longitude

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the following functions instead of directly accessing the properties:

```
results[0].geometry.location.lat()
```

and

```
results[0].geometry.location.lng()
```

The Google code is obfuscated and internally uses short variable names that can change from  one day to another.

Comment: And in your example, you don't have to create a new `google.maps.LatLng`; the `results[0].geometry.location` _is_ a google.maps.LatLng`.

Comment: @Sean Mickey,Maybe you can help with another problem, I can't seem to save that data to a variable in my script. How can I save it and use it?

Comment: @Alon All you should have to do is create a `var` and assign it to  `results[0].geometry.location`. If you want to access that value elsewhere in your script, you will have to assign it to a variable that has scope outside of the callback function, because `results[0]` (and its members) will only have scope within the callback function.

Comment: This makes sense since the lat and lng are function in the returned object. I was having the same issue and this was the only solution I found. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You MUST use

```
results[0].geometry.location.lat()
results[0].geometry.location.lng()
```

Using

```
results[0].geometry.location[0]
results[0].geometry.location[1]
```

returns undefined.

This was very confusing to me because the API sometimes returned a field named 'ab' and other times it returned 'Za'. Accessing the elements by their semantic value (with .lat and .lng) rather than the exact string name is far safer and more readable.